# WSO2 API Manager 2.1 - Store - OAuth2 Callback URL - Multiple URL

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I found this blog entry https://medium.com/@omindu/adding-multiple-application-callback-urls-in-wso2-api-manager-2-0-9391d4c6e8ed where said that we can use at callback url this expression: **regexp=(https://myapp.com/callback|https://testapp:8000/callback)**

But this is not working.
There is a way to add multiple urls to callback url?

Thanks,

Comment: I just tried this and it worked for me. Do you get any errors? What do you mean by not working?

Comment: I am sorry. We applied all the patches and It's working. Thank you.